# Empty mapkit coordinates system

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

I wanted to know whether it was posible to load a mapkit instance but with only the coordinates system ( I just need to place annonations in it, no matter an overlay layer below ).

I've been checking the docs and it seems you always need to load the satellite or the streets layer.

Comment: You could add a white (or whatever color you want) MKMapOverlay over the entire map.  It would still download map information and images but it wouldn't actually display the map.

Comment: I think you'll have to use an MKTileOverlay with canReplaceMapContent set to YES (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKTileOverlay_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKTileOverlay/canReplaceMapContent).

Comment: Thanks all. By now I'm using MKTileOverlay and it works as I wanted.